# What should my activity extend when application's minSdkVersion is 21?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, appcompatactivity

I am quite new to Android and Android Studio. I have created a new project and I have specified the `minSdkVersion as 21` and `target to 23`.

After AS is done with creating the activity I see that `MainActivity` is extending `AppCompatActivity` by default.

I read about `AppCompatActivity`  [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

It says that it is the **Base class for activities that use the *[support library](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/index.html)* action bar features.**

Now my question is:

1. Since my app's minSdkVersion is 21 why do I need my activity to extend **AppCompatActivity**?
2. Why does AS make my activity extend **AppCompatActivity** by default?
3. Is it necessary for my activity to extend **AppCompatActivity** or just extending **Activity** is enough considering my `minSdkVerion`?
4. What would I miss if my actvity don't extend **AppCompatActivity**?

Any explanation would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should extend AppCompatActivity if you are using action bar

[Read more here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/appbar/setting-up.html)

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), all activities that use the default theme have an ActionBar as an app bar. However, app bar features have gradually been added to the native ActionBar over various Android releases. As a result, the native ActionBar behaves differently depending on what version of the Android system a device may be using. By contrast, the most recent features are added to the support library's version of Toolbar, and they are available on any device that can use the support library.
>
> For this reason, you should use the support library's Toolbar class to implement your activities' app bars. Using the support library's toolbar helps ensure that your app will have consistent behavior across the widest range of devices. For example, the Toolbar widget provides a material design experience on devices running Android 2.1 (API level 7) or later, but the native action bar doesn't support material design unless the device is running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or later.

Comment: But I can do setActionBar(toolbar); instead of setSupportActionBar(toolbar); and getActionBar().setTitle("Title"); instead of getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");

Comment: As it mentions "app bar features have gradually been added to the native ActionBar over various Android releases.", so even though you are only supporting only range from 21 and above there may be some changes that could have gone in those 3 versions, so it leaves a possibility of actionbar behaving a little differently on 21 version than let's say 23( a bit unlikely) due to some feature change in those 2 releases. So if you can test and ensure that such changes do not appear between these versions, you can do what you mention

Comment: You are just thinking that I should extend AppCompatActivity if I am using ActionBar. So, are you not sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

AppCompatActivity gives you the additional functionality of ActionBar after api level 7.

Activity helps you avoid extra libraries but doesnt provide actiobBar feature.

Prior to revision 22.1.0 the Action bar was provided by extending ActionBarActivity which is deprecated now

Comment: But I can do setActionBar(toolbar); instead of setSupportActionBar(toolbar); and getActionBar().setTitle("Title"); instead of getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you said, indeed it is. We don't have to extends `AppCompatActivity`. But a lot of open source libs using `AppCompatActivity` to grab the feature to lower API level projects, and the third part libs are going to ask your `MainActivity` to extends `AppCompatActivity`. So, either you can implement your own *lib* or extends `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

`AppCompatActivity` is a part of support library, so you also have the benefit of using support library. In short, your activity which extended `AppCompatActivity` will have the capability of the Activity in the recent API (***but*** as long as the implementation of the capability is builded in the support library).

You can read the following from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html?#framework-apis):

> **Using Support versus Framework APIs**
>
> Support Libraries provide classes and methods that closely resemble APIs in the Android Framework. Upon discovering this, you may wonder if you should use the framework version of the API or the support library equivalent. Here are the guidelines for when you should use support library classes in place of Framework APIs:
>
> - **Compatibility for a Specific Feature** - If you want to support a recent platform feature on devices that a running earlier versions of the platform, use the equivalent classes and methods from the support library.
> - **Compatibility for Related Library Features** - More sophisticated support library classes may depend on one or more additional support library classes, so you should use support library classes for those dependencies. For example, the ViewPager support class should be used with FragmentPagerAdapter or the FragmentStatePagerAdapter support classes.
> - **General Device Compatibility** - If you do not have a specific platform feature you intend to use with your app in a backward compatible way, it is still a good idea to use support library classes in your app. For example, you may want to use ActivityCompat in place of the framework Activity class, so you can take advantage of newer features later on, such as incorporating the new permissions model introduced in Android 6.0 (API level 23).